# How to determine the rust-analyzer version used by VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

How can I find out which version of `rust-analyzer` is used by the extension with the same name in VSCode?

Answer (score -1):

Displaying the `rust-analyzer` version is possible via a palette command in VSCode:

- Open command palette <kbd>Ctrl/⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Type / select: `rust-analyzer: Show RA Version`

Under Linux, the extension installs the `rust-analyzer` binary into `${HOME}/.vscode/extensions`. Therefore, the reported version by the command should be in line with the output of

```bash
${HOME}/.vscode/extensions/rust-lang.rust-analyzer-*/server/rust-analyzer --version
```

(unless `rust-analyzer.server.path` is configured manually.)

Comment: What I don't understand yet is how that version relates to the versions shown on the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/releases) and the [changelog](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/thisweek). On first glance, there's no obvious connection to me.

Comment: Same problem - no idea now to translate this version to github's version. What...